# Do blessings stack?

Tags: ascendant

Do the effects of identical blessings stack? If I equip two Blessings of Hachiman in my body slots, will I have twice the chance of dodging attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can now say that they do indeed stack. I have two Blessings of Zephyrus in my body slots, and I'm triple jumping all over the place.